# How can I edit this code so that I can get the program to detect if no grades were entered when the prompt box is empty or cancel is hit?

Tags: javascript, average

Someone helped my with this earlier, but didn't give me 100% what I wanted. This program averages the grades that are entered, but what if no grades were entered? How do I detect whether or not the user entered grades into the promptbox, and if they didn't, how can I display that No Grades were entered in place of where it says "The Average of the grades you've entered is:"

Here's the Javascript

```js
 <script type = "text/javascript">
   //These list the variables that are used to activate the prompt box.
   var btn = document.querySelector('button'),
     res = document.getElementById('average');

 btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var val = prompt('Enter comma delimited grades to average'); //This defines the variable to propmt hte user to enter a value.
   val = val.length ? val.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',') : ''; //this gets the length of the form value in JQuery

   var count = val.length || 0; // no 0 division

   if (!count) {
     res.innerHTML = 'you must enter comma delimited numbers to average';
     return;
   } else {
     var average = val.reduce(function(a, b) { // is a loop
       return +a + +b;
     });

     res.innerHTML = (average /= count).toFixed(1); //Another way of writing document.write but without clearing the document. The average divides, or equals the count of the numbers entered.  
   }

 }); </script>
```

Here's the HTML

```html
<button id="avgBtn">Prompt</button>
<p>The average of the grades you've entered is: <span id="average"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this code with the one inside addEventListener() method.

```
var val = prompt('Enter comma delimited grades to average'); //This defines the variable to propmt the user to enter a value.
if(val) {
    val = val.length ? val.replace(/\s/g, '').split(',') : ''; //this gets the length of the form value in JQuery
    var count = val.length || 0, // no 0 division
    average = val.reduce(function(a, b) { // is a loop
        return +a + +b;
    });

    res.innerHTML = (average /= count).toFixed(1); //Another way of writing document.write but without clearing the document. The average divides, or equals the count of the numbers entered.  
}else {
    res.innerHTML = 'You must enter a comma delimited numbers to average';
    return;
}
```

When ever the prompt box leaves empty or with hitting cancel button, it will show the message.

Comment: That works perfectly! I really do appreciate the help. It's been killing me trying to figure it out.